# How do I reset another user’s password on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, passwords, troubleshooting, password-recovery

I’m troubleshooting a standard user’s account. She has forgot her password and I’m trying to change the password but there’s no options

My method was

**Home** > **Control Panel** > **User Accounts** > **User Accounts (Change account type)** > **person’s name Account** > **Change account password**

But **Change account password** is not available. Is there any other way to change the person’s password that I’m troubleshooting in order to get her stuff back?

Comment: Take note that changing another user’s password is a *destructive* operation. If the user in question has EFS-encrypted files they will be irreversibly lost.

Comment: Also, this is not a duplicate. It’s about changing another users password while administrative access is still possible.

Comment: An Administrator cannot change a user’s password only reset it.  The difference between the two actions is that changing the password requires knowledge of the current password and can only be done with the account in question.  If the user doesn’t know their password the only course of action is to reset the password (or give them more chances to figure it out)

Answer (score 1):

Open up Command Prompt (Run as Admin).

Type in `net user user_name new_password`.

If you would like to confirm the username, just do a `net user` to get a list of all the accounts.

You could also do `net user user_name * /domain`. You'll be asked to type in and confirm the password later.